# Omit specific keys from array of objects if the value is NULL

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have this array:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Homer Simpson",
    "age": "43",
    "start_time": null,
    "end_time": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Bart Simpson",
    "age": "14",
    "start_time": "2023-11-10T20:08:10Z",
    "end_time": "2023-11-10T20:08:10Z"
  }
];
```

How do I omit the `start_time` and `end_time` from each object if the value is NULL? I would like to end with this array:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Homer Simpson",
    "age": "43"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bart Simpson",
    "age": "14",
    "start_time": "2023-11-10T20:08:10Z",
    "end_time": "2023-11-10T20:08:10Z"
  }
];
```

I know I can loop through each object and push into a new array with the omitted values if the time values are null, but is there a more concise way of doing it? Is there a way I can use Array.filter?

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do this is to use mapping with `lodash` `pickBy` function.

It's a bit shorter and more elegant than using `reduce`.

[Reference](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pickBy)

```js
import {map, pickBy} from 'lodash';

const data = [
  {
    "name": "Homer Simpson",
    "age": "43",
    "start_time": null,
    "end_time": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Bart Simpson",
    "age": "14",
    "start_time": "2023-11-10T20:08:10Z",
    "end_time": "2023-11-10T20:08:10Z"
  }
];

const result = map(data, obj => pickBy(obj, (value, key) => value !== null));
```